# How can I remove spaces in highlighted text with Sublime Text?

Tags: string, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

If I highlight some text, i.e "sally came from home", is there a way to remove all the spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press

> ctrl + h

to bring up the find and replace menu

[image]

Then Click the following icon to only find in your current selection

[image]

Then enter in a space in the find and either click find_all and press delete, or add nothing to replace and click replace_all

Answer (score 2):

Use the find panel. Select "In Selection" and search for a space. Hit "Find All" and delete.

Alternatively, you could use the find & replace panel and just replace the spaces with nothing.